# Cannot move tools inside Visual Studio Form while Designing by mouse

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

The problem is that I cannot move tools as (TextEdit , Button , ComboBox or anything) inside the form while design by mouse dragging  but I can move them only by keyboard arrows
Gif Image Shows the Problem here ===>
[Gif Image Explains the Problem](https://jumpshare.com/v/QUEyO4vsDJKvtD02c8du)

I tried to Install and reinstall Visual Studio 2017 and 2012 and 2022 versions.
All versions have the same problem

Comment: What did that error say in the dialog? Is that a clean form, directly inheriting from the base class?

Comment: Check the gif Image that explains the error

Comment: I did check the gif but as it animates the error dialog is visible for 1ms and now I'm forced to watch the whole thing multiple times before I fully read the error message which might be relevant and should therefor be present in your question as plain text. What does the [form].designer.cs look like? Can you disable DevExpress and then still reproduce? Start  vs from the command line with `devenv /SafeMode`  (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022)